# State/building Overlays on Map for iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an app that requires overlays to be added to both states and individual buildings on a map view. I've seen a lot of demos done through WWDC and the like but I'm having a hard time finding out how to actually implement it. I'm not sure where or how to get the data and then how to put that into an overlay. All I know is that I would have to use MKPolygon in some way but that's it.

Could someone instruct me on how to do so?